# MySQL fetch the rows, which wont contain only the specific string / word

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want a MySQL query to return rows which don't have the only input string/phrase in it.

Example: I have table with the column name like

```
Sno  | sname
---------------
1    | AAA
2    | SSS
3    | Group Post
4    | Group Post, Test Run
5    | Group Post, Group Post
6    | Group Post, Group Post, My test Run
```

In the above table I want to eliminate the rows which have "Group Post" only in them. That means how many times Group Post exist in the row and there are no other phrases or words in them, then we can eliminate it.

So I want a query which will return

```
Sno  | sname
---------------
1    | AAA
2    | SSS
4    | Group Post, Test Run
6    | Group Post, Group Post, My test Run
```

In these rows some of them have Group Post in them. But along with the that we have other phrases in them.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is very hard to decipher as written.  Do you want rows 3 to be eliminated?  Or more than that?  Please provide an "after" example to go with your "before" example, I'm sure that will help clarify what you're looking to do.

Comment: Why can't you try it in php by getting all the row values and check it store which values were required

Comment: I'd use PHP, get the values in an array and explode the sname - go through the resulting array and pick and choose which I keep or throw out

Comment: @Kzqai: I want to fetch only the results like you edited in the post. 1,2,4,6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `REPLACE` function to filter the data.

Try this:

```
select * from my_table
 where length( replace( replace( sname, 'Group Post', '' ), ', ', '' ) ) > 0
```

***Refer to***:
[MySQL: REPLACE(str,from_str,to_str) Function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

Comment: Hi Ravinder, Thanks for the Answer. Your Query Solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

try a subquery for finding all the ids which have the string and then use not in for example

> ```
> SELECT * FORM {table_name} where id not in (select * from {table_name} where sname = "YOUR_STRING");
> ```

Comment: This will not solve the OP problem. Plz read the question clearly

Answer (score 0):

select Sno,sname
from table_name
where length(replace(sname,'Group Post','')) > 0;

Answer (score 0):

***QUERY***

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE sname NOT LIKE '%Group Post'
```

***[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e3f0e)***

hope this will help you...!